# Include java class from other module? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm building a LibGDX project with 2 modules: `core` and `android`.
For those not familiar with LibGDX: the `android` module contains the launcher for the cross-platform code in the `core` module.

I want to include a class from the `android` module in the `core` module, in order to call a function of the class in the `android` module.

How can I do this (in Android Studio)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Keep library parallel with your android project

For eg: My library name is mylibs and it is located under D:\Android_Workspace

So My project must be located under D:\Android_Workspace and my android project's name is MyApp

But both will be parally located

Watch this video for all steps => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk

Comment: I don't want to add a library. I just want to get access to a class from the other module.